# Drupal shortcuts - link with question mark included

Tags: 7, routes, navigation

When I add a link to shortcut set which looks like this:

admin/work?date_filter

shortcut module changes this question mark sign "?" into this "%3F" and this link doesn't work anymore. I believe I can't avoid it - looks like it's a bug, so my question is how to add link as a shortcut programically?

Comment: It's a browser rule to convert special characters. May I know why you need such character in your URL? It may help me to answer more accurate.

Comment: @DharaShah It's not browser rule. I've checked it. Chrome doesn't translate question mark into ASCII code. As for the link, it's a long story, but it must stay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shortcut module is more strict about valid URLs it can use compared to what the menu module will allow (e.g. no external URLs, no query param).

One way to circumvent this is to use [`hook_menu`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) in a custom module to define a valid path that redirects where you want it to go and add that path to your shortcut set.

```
function MYMODULE_menu() {
  $items['MYMODULE/work'] = array(
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'page callback' => 'drupal_goto',
    'page arguments' => array('admin/work', array('query' => array('date_filter' => 'XXX'))),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK
  );
  return $items;
}
```

This makes `MYMODULE/work` a valid path for your shortcut set.